# Где ставить запятые в этом предложении? "Ты ведь знаешь что такое хорошо и плохо"

Tags: запятые

Где ставить запятые в этом предложении?

"Ты ведь знаешь что такое хорошо и плохо".

Answer (score 1):

Одну запятую - перед придаточной частью СПП.

*Ты ведь знаешь, что такое хорошо и плохо.*